# Failed to install JSON/XS.pm

Tags: perl

I am getting:

```
Can't locate JSON/XS.pm in @INC (you may need to install the JSON::XS module)
(@INC contains:
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.1/darwin-2level
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.24.1
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.24.1/darwin-2level
/usr/local/lib/perl5/5.24.1
.
) at get.pl line 13.
```

(Line breaks added for readability.)

I have tried installing this module using cpan and getting the following message:

```
Can't write to cpanm home '/Users/sa/.cpanm': You should fix it with chown/chmod first.
```

I was wondering on what and where to find it to fix it?

---

```
$ ls -al ~/.cpanm
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   5 root staff  170 Feb 20 10:37 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 50 sa   staff 1700 Feb 20 13:51 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root staff   51 Feb 20 10:37 build.log -> /Users/sa/.cpanm/work/1487615857.2117/build.log
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root staff   41 Feb 20 10:37 latest-build -> /Users/sa/.cpanm/work/1487615857.2117
drwxr-xr-x   4 root staff  136 Feb 20 10:37 work
```

Comment: From the error it looks like the permissions are too restrictive on the `.cpanm` folder in your home directory.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen yes. I tried to change the permissions using `chmod 0755 .cpanm/`. It still could not write to that.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -al ~/.cpanm`?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen `total 16
drwxr-xr-x   5 root    staff   170 Feb 20 10:37 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 50 sa  staff  1700 Feb 20 13:51 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff    51 Feb 20 10:37 build.log -> /Users/sa/.cpanm/work/1487615857.2117/build.log
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root    staff    41 Feb 20 10:37 latest-build -> /Users/sa/.cpanm/work/1487615857.2117
drwxr-xr-x   4 root    staff   136 Feb 20 10:37 work`

Comment: Is cpanm installing to your local lib? Perhaps it is installing to another local/lib/ perl version directory?

Comment: Did you run `sudo cpanm` at some point? Because I don't think root should own stuff under `/Users/sa`.

Comment: @sai currently the `root` user owns the `.cpanm` directory and no other groups have write permissions. Folders in your $HOME directory should be owned by your user account (in most cases). Try changing the ownership of the directory to your user `chown sa ~/.cpanm`

Comment: @melpomene Yes. I ran the sudo cpanm command. I'm brand new to perl  and taking steps blindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did `sudo cpanm` at some point, and it created files in your home directory that belong to `root` instead of `sa`. Fix:

```
sudo chown -R sa:staff ~/.cpanm
```

In the future, use `cpanm --sudo` instead of `sudo cpanm` to avoid this problem. (It also avoid using root until necessary.)

Comment: Or use `cpanm --sudo` which solves the problem in a different way.

Comment: @hobbs, Fixed. Not familiar with all the options of `cpanm` since I've never installed it since the only reason to do so I've been giving is that it's better in low-resource environments such as embedded systems, and I'm not using such an environment.